# Tool for analyzing C++ sources (MSVC)

Tags: c++, code-analysis, visual-c++

I need a tool which analyzes C++ sources and says what code isn't used. Size of sources is ~500mb

Comment: Lol -- "Analyze" means to examing. "Analize" means to turn into an anus?

Comment: >"Analize" means to turn into an anus?
you know better

Comment: Andreo, you should update your question to refer to "coverage".  Analyse (or with z) when referring to source code will probably be interpreted as static analysis, of which code coverage is a very small part (if included at all).

Comment: Code coverage is NOT a kind of static analysis; in fact it is a dynamic analysis.   I suspect OP doesn't care if the analysis is static or dynamic as long as he gets an answer to his question.  Code coverage is a good way to get a pretty good approximation of the truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PC-Lint is good.  If it needs to be free/open source your choices dwindle.  Cppcheck is free, and will check for unused private functions.  I don't think that it looks for things like uninstantiated classes like PC-Lint.

Answer (score 0):

Once again, I'll throw [AQTime](http://www.automatedqa.com) into the discussion. Has static code analysis for most, if not all, of the supported languages. I didn't really go into that part though, I mainly used the dynamic profilers (memory, performance and so on).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a code coverage tool  (dynamic analysis) to get an idea of what code isn't
being executed, and then hand analyze to see if that code is really useless.

If you want a static analysis, you need a tool that can read the entire
500Mb of source code (est. 20 million lines? Wow!) and compute a
conservative estimate of what is used.  This requires doing a points-to
analysis over the entire system.

Here's why: If you leave out any module Z, and
decide that FOO is unused, you
might find out later that Z happened to be the one that used FOO,
or more subtly, Z copied a pointer value that happened to have 
&FOO in it to a third module M that in turn called the "unused" function
throught the pointer.

What this means is that no static analysis tool that reads just
single modules (compilation units) can answer this question safely.
And at your scale, you can't afford to make dumb mistakes.

My company, Semantic Designs has done points-to analysis for 35 million line systems
of C code using our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit.  DMS
*can* read very large systems of source code.  It required
a custom tool, not so much because the source code was in an odd (archiac)
dialect of C++ (systems in extremely modern dialects can't be this big,
not enough time to code them!), but rather because in very large systems
there are other peculiar factors at play.  For the C system we did,
there was a custom dynamic linker, and that affected the points-to analysis,
which in turn had to be customized.

Because systems of the scale you are discussing alway have surprises like this (BIBSEH: "Because In Big Systems, Everything Happens"), you will
likely need a custom tool to answer the question.   DMS is designed
to be customized.
See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html
and http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html

Answer (score -2):

Code coverage tool is what you need, but you will have to run our program through all functionality and see what is repoted as unused.  Since the code could be DLL exported functions you will have to make sure nothing uses them externally.  Some code coverage tools: Purify, CTC++, Boundschecker may have code coverage functionality if I remember right and a bunch of other tools.

Be very careful about removing any function that may have been exported without knowing what external program may be linking/using it.

Comment: I think code coverage is different than what I read the original question to be - which is static analysis of code that can never be called.

Comment: @AlexC, Code coverage refers to how much of your code is exercised by the tests you have run.

Comment: Maybe you guys missed the point of my post, if the C++ code compiles to a DLL there is no way of knowing what is calling that code unless you have access to all the code that may be accessing it which may not be the case.  Using a code coverage tool while using the system may help determine what is getting called via the exported DLL interface which state analysis may not be able to pickup (especially if it's dynamically bound by name or ordinal).